# Location of Documentation for Groovy Process.waitFor()

Tags: groovy

I am trying to find the javadoc style documentation for Groovy's Process.waitFor() method.

I am currently using the method, so I know it exists.

It is shown in example code on the codehaus website: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Process+Management

Yet, it is not referenced in the Groovy documentation for Process:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html

I would think this would be easy to Google for, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The waitFor method is in [Java's Process class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29)

Comment: And also in [Java 1.6's Process class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html).

Comment: It's been part of Java since 1.0, so yes it will be there too ;-)